# Was not expected batch error

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch LAN chatroom I'm making and the user section is working fine but my admin one with options to edit the chatlog break it.

When entering text to chat I get wordhere was not expected at this time. Its to do with the if `%text%` EQU lines I have for the managing.

How can I fix this here is my code. I need to be able to type anything in and have it sent to the dictionary file to be displayed BUT if the EQU terms are entered do their actions.

```
:A
cls
echo.
echo Type What You Want To Chat // Press The "e" Key To Logoff Correctly
echo Type "manage" To Manage The Chat History
echo.
set /p text=
if %text% EQU e goto exiting
if %text% EQU E goto exiting
if %text% EQU manage goto managing
if %text% EQU Manage goto managing
echo.
echo >> Directory.txt [Admin] %name% says: %text%
echo.
goto :A
```

The exact same code without the if lines works fine but I need them.

Say i type in: this is test text, it will error at: is
here is a picture:
[image: error example]

Fixed! (if "%text%" EQU "e" goto exiting) Fixed it, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%text%" EQU "e" goto exiting
```

etc. is the standard fix.

The `if` syntax is specific: if *string* op *string*

the quotes specify that there is a string that *may* contain separators like spaces.

BTW, `if /i ...` will make the comparison case-insensitive.

Another approach is

```
if not defined var ...
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it i cant believe i forgot the " "  Some things work without them.

Comment: @TaylorLightfoot, yes, it can work without the `""` as long as `%text%` is not empty; as soon as it is empty, you are comparing nothing to something (`if  EQU e`), which raises a syntax error; using quotes, you are actually comparing `""` to `"e"`; the `""` also have the advantage that some poisonous characters do not harm the code, for example `&` which is used to concatenate multiple commands...

Comment: in this case, even a space is a "poisonous character".

Comment: Yeah i know I just forgot to add them in for some reason. Thanks for the reminder. it all works perfect now